# how do i create global service for iphone app in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, service, singleton

I'm new to ios and swift and really not sure of what approach to use for global service.
As of now my approach is - i create an object of NSTimer and call a fucntion A() at regular interval of time of 2 minutes. I need to call this at multiple scenarios as described below :

1. When i launch my app - at that time i need to  start the NSTimer and call A().
2. One of sub-pages of app has button name "Show" and when i click same function should be called.
3. When app goes in the background, same function needs to be called at regular interval of 2 minutes.

Here is my confusion - i need to create single instance only so that no mulitple instance is exist and if when any scenario it should terminate the running function.

I need to do this in swift only.
Please suggest or provide any example if exists.

thanks

Comment: Hope this helps you - https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Answer (score 7):

Let is assume, your class as SomeService. Here is how you can create singleton:

```
 class SomeService {


  static let sharedInstance : SomeService = {
    //Do any computations needed to have the args for SomeService initializer, if not you can omit this closure and directly assign SomeService() to sharedInstance
    return SomeService() //<--Call the designated initialiser to instantiate the object.
    }()

   //Other methods of the class....
}
```

Basically, it is just a class level let constant of the same type of your class. Hope this helps.

You can access the singleton as follows:

```
SomeService.sharedInstance
```

Comment: In my tests `SomeService` is never initialized unless you access `sharedInstance` once. Is there a way to make sure it gets initialized without any external action?